# Unable to run multiple Jbehave stories using the metafilter with multiple meta tags using this maven command

Tags: groovy, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I am unable to run multiple Jbehave stories using the metafilter with multiple meta tags using this maven command - problem with the meta filter specification format that I'm using.

But I can able to run with only one meta filter, but not able to run with many using this below format

```
clean verify -DJIRAPROJECT=MCODEEW -DJIRA_LABEL=N_OSG -DENVIRONMENT=UAT -Dmetafilter=groovy:MNEW_123&&groovy:MNEW_789 -f pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

`groovy:` prefix should be specified only once (at the beginning):

```
... -Dmetafilter=groovy:MNEW_123&&MNEW_789 ...
```

More details on JBehave meta filters can be found in [the official documentation](https://jbehave.org/reference/latest/meta-filtering.html).

Comment: Still its running only this MNEW_123 and not another tag